# Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat) doesn't change MIME type

Tags: c#, mime-types, system.drawing

I'm doing `Bitmap.Save(MemoryStream, ImageFormat.Gif)` on a JPG source image, but when checking the MIME type of the MemoryStream the image is saved to, I still get `image/jpeg`. Judging from the greatly reduced quality of the returned image, I'm certain that the actual conversion is taking place, but at the same time I'm also sure that the MIME type is also being read correctly.

Could there be something wrong with my code or is this normal for `Bitmap.Save`?

Comment: a `MemoryStream` is just a stream of bytes - what mime type property are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (judging by your previous question) this is ASP.NET / HTTP in general you have to set the content type header to set the mime type of the data that you are delivering:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
```

A bitmap saved to .NET stream is just a stream of bytes and does not hold a mime type by itself.

Comment: I don't want to hard code that, so I'm setting the ContentType by reading the MIME type of the stream/byte[] through an interop call. The Bitmap I'm saving is actually initialized through a FileStream from a source image on disk, which I think does store its MIME type. I think what's happening is that the same byte array is being carried over from method to method, and the part of the byte[] that stores the MIME type (first 256 bytes) is not affected after the conversion.

Comment: @rafale: This sounds like over-engineering to me - you already have a call to `Bitmap.Save()` that you pass `ImageFormat.Gif` - you could set the mime type right before that - *you specify gif anyway*

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now. I didn't realize that MIME types aren't necessarily part of the file/byte[], and that it would be easier to just set them manually based on the format I'm converting to. Just a misunderstanding on my part.